# How to add one more command in crontab?

Tags: laravel, cron

How can I add some commands in crontab?

```
0 * * * * cd /var/www/cron && /usr/loc/php artisan schedule:run 2>&1 >> /var/log/logs.log
0 5 * * * cd /var/www/cron && /usr/loc/php artisan present:run 2>&1 >> /var/log/present.log
```

Comment: You already have two, so that seems to have worked. What are you having trouble with? Add a new line like the ones you already have

Comment: @brombeer I've just thought that it had a mistake because it does not work

Comment: Might want to rephrase the question then, so you added the 2nd line but it doesn't run at 5:00? Do none of the jobs run or just the last? Laravel has [Running The Scheduler](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling#running-the-scheduler)

Comment: @brombeer only last

Comment: What is `php artisan present:run` supposed to do? Is that available via a 3rd party package?

Comment: @brombeer There is just the command for calling and I am sure that it works because it is run when I do it through console

Comment: Why not just schedule the artisan command using task scheduling? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add new line in crone tab as below

```
* * * * * cd /var/www/cron && /usr/loc/php artisan mail:send 2>&1 >> /var/log/mail.log
```